# texture does not affect volume shader

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

the white part should have the volume in blue and the black part in red but it doesn't work
I leave you an image that explains the problem better

[image]

Comment: It's going to depend on the texture coordinate you use.  Typically I'd expect an image texture to describe a surface, but you can project it over an axis if you want.  Long story short: An image really doesn't have anything to say about a volume.  It doesn't have any depth.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, because you're dealing with volumes, you need to use 3D Textures! :)

You can get these by using procedural textures with the type set to 3D. To get that squiggly shape, for example, you could do something like this:

[image]

Then, to get that circular shape, you could do something like this:

[image]

You could then add them together to get something like this:

[image]

If you only want the shape to appear on the front of the cube, you can use a noise texture to create a mask for the added textures:

[image]

You can then multiply the mask with the result of the added textures. This isn't perfect, but you can play with the settings to get what you want:

[image]

Finally, you can adjust the result with a color ramp and then plug that into the factor of the mix shader to get what you'd like:

[image]

Procedural shading is tricky at first, but it's really powerful! Best of luck!